# Injecting a factory in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Hello I can't call a factory function. When I use it I have the next message

[image]

Here my factory

[image]

And the controller with the call

[image]

When I try to print Account, it is undefined. Can anyone see my error? Thanks

Comment: Please copy-paste the code to the question as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: add Account service to the controller.before `function` and after `$location`

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I'm honestly curious as to why you didn't post that as an answer? I see people doing it a lot on SO

Comment: @z0r to be honest, I don't know ;)  but I think that was because I have seen this question a lot. anyway! Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Account` is not declared as a dependency of the controller. Change it to:

```
.controller('forgotController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Account',
                                 function($scope, $location, Account) {
```

For this to work, you need to make sure `Account` is available to the injector for your module. So when you declare the module that your controller is in, if it's not in the same module, be sure to include `AccountService` as a [module dependency](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#dependencies). For example:

```
angular.module('ForgotModule', ['AccountService'])
    .controller('forgotController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Account',
                                     function($scope, $location, Account) {
```

Comment: @DavidLuque OK, I added some info about module dependencies too.